# Is the SSL now obsolete?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, gnutls

I begin learn the information protection and start from OpenSSL. But I read on the Wikipedia that SSL have trouble with security that still not solved and anyone must use TLS instead. Is it true?  Is it mean that SSL now obsolete? (because there appears other way of information protection instead fixing SSL)

Comment: OpenSSL is just the name, it supports TLS too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLS is just the newer name for the protocol formerly named SSL. If you look at the protocol level you see that TLS 1.0 is practically SSL 3.1, TLS 1.1 is SSL 3.2 etc. Versions up to and including version SSL 3.0 are considered broken and should not be used any longer.
Because of this naming in practice "SSL" and "TLS" are often used to mean the same protocol group and often you find also "SSL/TLS" to refer to this protocol group. Usually only if a version number is added they refer to this version only. Libraries like OpenSSL, PolarSSL, MatrixSSL etc implement the protocol group, i.e. SSL and TLS.

To add to this naming confusion "SSL" is often used together with protocols like SMTP (send mail) or IMAP (access mail) to mean a secure connection from start while "TLS" is used in this context to mean secure connection after issuing a specific `STARTTLS` command. It is better to use "implicit" and "explicit" SSL/TLS instead.

Answer (score 4):

SSL as a protocol is insecure, and TLS should be used instead.  However, people often use the name 'SSL' to refer to SSL as well as TLS.  Furthermore, it is often included in many systems as a fallback measure, so that connections can have some security, at least, if TLS isn't available.  The merits of doing this are questionable, as some people feel that this allows developers to be lazy, or not even realize they're using an insecure method.